# Google Calendar Api throws PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate the Google Calendar API into my project. The project is a .NET Standard 2.1 IOS project.
If I follow the steps of the Google Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/dotnet)
then my code looks like this:

```cs
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace CalendarQuickstart
{
    /* Class to demonstrate the use of Calendar events list API */
    class Program
    {
        /* Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
         If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved token.json/ folder. */
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                UserCredential credential;
                // Load client secrets.
                using (var stream =
                       new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    /* The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                     automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time. */
                    string credPath = "token.json";
                    var createCredentialTask = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true));

                    credential = createCredentialTask.Result; // <-- This causes the PlatformNotSupportedException

                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                }

                // Create Google Calendar API service.
                var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName
                });

                // Define parameters of request.
                EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
                request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
                request.ShowDeleted = false;
                request.SingleEvents = true;
                request.MaxResults = 10;
                request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

                // List events.
                Events events = request.Execute();
                Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
                if (events.Items == null || events.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
                    return;
                }
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is that the line `credential = createCredentialTask.Result;` throws the following exception:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.get_SupportsRedirectConfiguration()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object , BindingFlags , Binder , Object[] , CultureInfo )
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.InvokeNativeHandlerMethod(String , Object[] )
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetSupportsRedirectConfiguration()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.get_SupportsRedirectConfiguration()
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateAndConfigureClientHandler()
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow..ctor(Initializer initializer)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow..ctor(Initializer initializer)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Initializer initializer, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)
```

As far as I know it's because of the HttpClientHandler which seems to be incompatible but I can't find any solutions on the internet.
Maybe there is someone here who knows the problem and has a solution for it, , because I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: "The project is a .NET Standard 2.1 IOS project." - as in, using Xamarin? That's not a supported platform for the library - see https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/main/FAQ.md#why-arent-unity-xamarin-or-uwp-supported

Comment: Yes im using Xamarin... So i can toss the google api library and need to call google api manually?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid we don't support Xamarin at the moment. (I don't know whether the move to .NET 6 for MAUI will help make it easier to support - it's unlikely to make it easier to test, which is one of the problems we'd be worried about.) I *suspect* that if you implement your own HttpClientInitializer to do the auth, you could use the rest of the library - but it would still be basically unsupported.

Comment: Is there any guide on how to implement a custom HttpClientInitializer?

Comment: I tried to implement my own HttpClientFactory that uses SocketsHttpHandler (.NET 6) instead of HttpClientHandler.
That worked to create a service. But causes other problems.
When using the service and calling `_service.Calendars.Get(calendarId).Execute();`
there is another Exception:

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error setting value to 'Kind' on 'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Calendar'.
 ---> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper delegate-invoke) void <Module>:invoke_callvirt_void_Calendar_string (Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Calendar,string)' while running in aot-only mode.`

Comment: More reasons we don't support Xamarin, I'm afraid.

Comment: The funny thing is that it works on simulator but on device the exception is thrown